# How to view an image file's dimension with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign variables that store the height and width of an image from the local "img" folder. I tried something along the lines of

```
myWidth = (("img/myImage.png").naturalWidth);
```

but as far as I can tell, that only works if the image is already present somewhere on the page. Is there a way to do this by getting Javascript to view the file's properties in the folder?

EDIT: I'm not doing anything too technical. I just have 600 or so small images that need to be in separate divs that are the same pixel width and height as the image, and each image is different. I'm trying to write a script to generate all the code for my css without having to type it all in manually.

Comment: JS can't access files in folders, you've to somehow [load the image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) before retrieving its size.

Comment: @Teemu Technically incorrect. It's the HTML5 APIs that don't allow local file access. You can definitely access files in folders with JavaScript if the environment offers such APIs.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 So, we're going to build up an API and give that as an answer ..? Or maybe use ActiveX ..?

Comment: @Teemu It is possible that OP might be running a node script, which *does* have access to files.

Comment: files can be accessed with `node`  if this is server side code this can be achieved

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 "_from local "img" folder_" ...

Comment: @Teemu Exactly.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Well, I can very well then recommend to use ActiveX, no difference on nitpicking ...

Comment: @Teemu That would be a valid solution as well, but OP should clarify on the environment that he is running the script in.

Comment: I edited the post for a little more information. This won't need to be made available anywhere on the Internet, I'm just trying to save some time writing some very tedious code.

Comment: @TimGraupner So, are you running your script in a browser or in Node?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Browser.

Comment: Why not just load the images to the divs, and style the divs to adapt to the size of the images?

Comment: @TimGraupner Since it's supposed to be a "quick and dirty" script to generate CSS files, have you considered generating it in Node or use a proper [CSS preprocessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_preprocessor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Image element to get the dimensions. I have previously created a tool that fetches image dimensions via JavaScript for an SO question. You can see it in action here: https://codepen.io/NikxDa/pen/apegZa

Necessary part:

```
var img = new Image ();

// Handle onload (will contain data after file has loaded)
img.onload = function () {
    alert ("The dimensions are: " + this.width + "x" + this.height);
};

// Load the file by fileUrl
img.src = <fileUrl>;
```

Hope it helps.